# Optimal solution for changing the value in Dictionary for the value int []

Tags: c#

I am looking for solution to change value in dictionary. 
My dictionary look that:

```
public static Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, int[]>> lastMeter;
```

I very often need to change one value for array `int[]`.
Is there any option for change only one value in array?

The only thing that comes to my mind look that:

```
var tab = lastMeter[tag.ScannerMac][tag.TagMac];
tab[3] = 5;
lastMeter[tag.ScannerMac][tag.TagMac] = tab;
```

But this does not seem to me a good solution because of the frequency of this process.

Comment: Dict-access by key has O(1). Accessing a value in an array by index is also O(1), so why exactly do you consider not "good solution" here.

Comment: The assignment back to the dictionary in the 3rd line is not needed. Arrays are reference types. When you get the `tab` variable on the first line, it's a reference to the _same array_ that's still in the dictionary. Updating a value in that `tab` array will update the array in the dictionary, too, because it's the same array.

Comment: You could simply do this: `lastMeter[tag.ScannerMac][tag.TagMac][3] = 5;`

Comment: The readability seems the only problem here; you could wrap your `Dictionary<long, Dictionary<long, int[]>>` into a custom class exposing a method `void ChangeTab(int index, int value)`

Comment: ok, thanks you guys it is enough solution for me. Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to reassign. Because the dictionary works with reference.
You can use that.

```
lastMeter[tag.ScannerMac][tag.TagMac][3] = 5
```

Comment: You wrote the same what other people in the comments

Comment: I didn't see comments. Just trying to help @SilnyToJa